# How to download csv file with koajs

Tags: node.js, csv, attachment, koa.js

I'm using koajs as a framework for nodejs. I try to create csv data and response it to client but not working

```
let fields = ['code', 'status'];
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    json2csv({data: data, fields: fields }, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(response);
        }
    });
});
return p.then(data => {
    let fileName = 'promotioncode-' + moment().unix();
    ctx.response.attachment(fileName + '.csv');
    ctx.response.type = 'application/ms-excel';
    ctx.body = data;
})
```

The response is plan text data instead of attachment file
[Here is response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyR8d.png)

[Here is response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F5FJ.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to send a downloadable file attached to the body you need to create a read stream of the file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

ctx.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${result}`);
ctx.statusCode = 200;
ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(result);
```

Note: in result you have the file path

Comment: I perfomed your idea but received next error: "Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long [here all the CSV string that i expect to download]". My filename is "products.csv"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
ctx.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}.csv`);
ctx.statusCode = 200;
ctx.body = data;
```